# Make n number of lists with specific names

Tags: python

I'm working with matrices. I have one here which is described as a list which contains a list for every row. I was trying to group every row into a separate list with a specific name. For example, for the matrix [[0, 2, 1, 4], [1, 1, 2, 6], [2, 1, 1, 7]], I want to create 3 lists named row1, row2, row3, with every list in its corresponding variable. This is what I tried:

```
names = ["row1", "row2", "row3", "row4", "row5", "row6"]
for i in range(len(coeffs)):
    str(names[i]) = coeffs[i]
```

However, this gives me an error.

```
SyntaxError: can't assign to function call
```

How do I go about this?

Comment: where is coeffs ?

Comment: `matrix = [[0, 2, 1, 4], [1, 1, 2, 6], [2, 1, 1, 7]]
row1 = matrix[0]
row2 = matrix[1]
row3 = matrix[2]
print(row1)`

Comment: @KenGeelhoed, not the best way to do it. I wanna do it with a for loop, since the number of rows wouldn't always be known to me. That is why the question says "n number of lists".